# How to plot y-axis on the right of the figure? Without having to make subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

How can I change this code to make both: the y-axis and the y-axis label appear to the right? Which arguments should I pass on to plt.ylabel?

```
plt.matshow(set_color_matrix, interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap)
plt.title("Crystal Growth by DLA", y=1.08)
plt.xlabel("x", fontdict=dict(weight='bold'))
plt.ylabel("y", fontdict=dict(weight='bold'), rotation=0)
plt.savefig("Gifs_and_Images/{}_walkers.png".format(label), dpi=200)
```

Comment: what does ax has to do with plt? I don't understand how that answer relates to my case. If I'm not mistaken, you have to create a subplot. Is there a more direct way?

Comment: plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft='off', labelright='on')

Comment: Why don't you answer the question, instead of commenting it ? You're clearly answering the question.

Comment: @NikitaGupta thank you :) the numbers move to the right, however the ticks don't. How can I move them as well? BTW as IMCoins suggests you should put this as the answer. I will upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got it working just how I wanted without having to make a subplot.

```
plt.tick_params(labelleft='off', labelright='on', direction='in', right='on', left='off', bottom='off')
```

Thanks @NikitaGupta for the suggestion.